# Seeking chiral anomaly EFT example

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics

If an effective field theory has a chiral anomaly it means that chiral symmetry isn't a symmetry of the underlying theory which has been cut off to make the EFT. My question is whether there's a good example where this can seen explicitly. The kind of thing I'm picturing would be an EFT at cutoff A which has no chiral symmetry, while the same EFT at cutoff B << A has chiral symmetry which is anomalous.